The impact of removing an edge on the connectivity of these graphs.
The vertex connectivity $\kappa(G)$ of a graph G, also called connectivity, is the minimum size of a vertex cut. $G-xy$ is a graph obtained by removing an edge $xy$ from $G$.
We can easily prove the following lemma. (I can't recall the exact source).
Lemma 1. Let $G$ be a graph. Then $\kappa(G)-1\le \kappa(G-xy)\le \kappa(G)$.
But I do not know whether the equality condition for the inequality on the left is characterized.
So I started with some simple cases. For example, when the minimum degree $\delta(G)=\kappa(G)$, removing an edge $vy$ which is incident with a vertex $v$ with degree $d_G(v)=\delta(G)$, we have $\kappa(G-vy)=\kappa(G)-1$ since $\delta(G-xy)=\delta(G)-1$.
But if for any given $k$ a graph with $\delta(G)>\kappa(G)=k$, are there still examples that satisfy  the existence of an edge $xy$ such that $\kappa(G-xy)=\kappa(G)-1$?

Consider a graph $G$ consisting of two copies of the triangle $K_3$ connected by a single edge $e$. Then $\kappa(G) = 1$, $\delta(G) = 2$ and $\kappa(G - e) = 0 = \kappa(G) - 1$.
This example can be generalized as follows. Let $k > 0$ and $G$ be a graph consisting of two copies of the complete graph $K_{k + 2}$ connected by $k$ pairwise non-adjacent edges. Then $\kappa(G) = k$, $\delta(G) = k + 1$ and $\kappa(G - e) = k - 1 = \kappa(G) - 1$ for any edge $e$ connecting vertices from different copies of $K_{k + 2}$.
